# Android SQLiteDatabase fails to either insert or query

Tags: android, database, insert

I have an app that uses multiple databases. Currently, I am having a problem with just one of them. It stores an event for a calendar in the database. Its SQLiteOpenHelper looks like this:

```
public class PlanSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The database version.
public static final int VERSION = 1;

//The String keys of the database name and columns.
public static final String DB_NAME = "plans_db.sqlite";
public static final String PLANS_TABLE = "plans";
public static final String PLAN_ID = "id";
public static final String PLAN_NAME = "name";
public static final String PLAN_YEAR = "year";
public static final String PLAN_MONTH = "month";
public static final String PLAN_DAY = "day";
public static final String PLAN_PRIORITY = "priority";
public static final String PLAN_TIME = "time";
public static final String PLAN_END = "end";
public static final String SET_APPT = "set_appt";
public static final String PLAN_ALARM = "alarm";


public PlanSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createTable(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }

private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(
            "create table " + PLANS_TABLE + " ( " +
            PLAN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null, " +
            PLAN_NAME + " text, " +
            PLAN_YEAR + " integer, " +
            PLAN_MONTH + " integer, " +
            PLAN_DAY + " integer, " +
            PLAN_PRIORITY + " integer, " +
            PLAN_TIME + " integer, " +
            PLAN_END + " integer, " +
            SET_APPT + " integer, " +
            PLAN_ALARM + " integer );" );
}
}
```

This is the process:
The user goes to a screen to create a new calendar item (called a PlanItem). It has certain options, they select the ones they want, and they hit "ok." The PlanItem is made and passed to a method in the Application class for the app, which looks like:

```
/**
 * Called to save a PlanItem to the SQLiteDatabase.
 * @param item = the item to save to the database.
 * @param newItem = true if the item is new, false if it exists but was edited.
 * @return true if successful, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean savePlanItem(PlanItem item, boolean newItem) {

    try {

        //Create the ContentValues.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //Put the values in.
        values.put(PLAN_NAME, item.getName());
        values.put(PLAN_YEAR, item.getYear());
        values.put(PLAN_MONTH, item.getMonth());
        values.put(PLAN_DAY, item.getDay());
        values.put(PLAN_TIME, item.getTime());
        values.put(PLAN_END, item.getEnd());
        values.put(SET_APPT, item.isSetAppt() ? 1 : 0);
        values.put(PLAN_PRIORITY, item.getPriorityInt());
        values.put(PLAN_ALARM, item.isAlarm() ? 1 : 0);

        if (newItem) {

            //Put into the database.
            long id = plansDatabase.insert(PLANS_TABLE, null, values);

            if (id == -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {

            //Update the database.
            String where = String.format("%s = ?", PLAN_ID);
            plansDatabase.update(PLANS_TABLE, values, where, new String[] { item.getId() + "" });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    //Since it succeeded, return true.
    return true;
}
```

The boolean newItem just tells the method if the item was created or edited. My problem is in the creation. As you can see, it uses a SQLiteDatabase.insert() method. I even grab the id of the new row and test it against -1 (it returns -1 if there was an error according to Android documentation). Even so, the method returns true, which means that it saved correctly.
Then as soon as it is saved, the Activity that allows the user to create the item finishes and goes back to the Activity that displays it. In onResume(), it has a call to the Application class to get the PlanItems for that day. It looks like:

```
/**
 * Called to get the agenda items for a particular day.
 * @param date = the date to get agenda items for.
 * @return the ArrayList of PlanItems for the day.
 */
public ArrayList<PlanItem> getDailyAgenda(Date d) {

    //Make a new date.
    Date date = new Date(d.getDay(), d.getMonth(), d.getYear());

    //Create the ArrayList.
    ArrayList<PlanItem> items = new ArrayList<PlanItem>();

    //Set up a query.
    Cursor cursor = plansDatabase.query(PLANS_TABLE, new String[] {PLAN_ID, PLAN_NAME, PLAN_YEAR,
            PLAN_MONTH, PLAN_DAY, PLAN_PRIORITY, PLAN_TIME, PLAN_END, SET_APPT, PLAN_ALARM},
            String.format(" %s = ? AND %s = ? AND %s = ? ", PLAN_YEAR, PLAN_MONTH, PLAN_DAY),
            new String[] {String.valueOf(date.getYear()), String.valueOf(date.getMonth()),
            String.valueOf(date.getDay())}, null, null, null);

    //Move the cursor to the first position.
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    //If there are items...
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        //Initialize variables.
        long id;
        String name;
        int year, month, day, time, end, priority;
        boolean setAppt, alarm;
        PlanItem item;


        //Go through the database and get everything.
        do {

            //Get the values.
            id = cursor.getLong(0);
            name = cursor.getString(1);
            year = cursor.getInt(2);
            month = cursor.getInt(3);
            day = cursor.getInt(4);
            priority = cursor.getInt(5);
            time = cursor.getInt(6);
            end = cursor.getInt(7);
            setAppt = cursor.getInt(8) == 1;
            alarm = cursor.getInt(9) == 1;

            //Create a PlanItem and add it to the ArrayList.
            item = new PlanItem(id, name, year, month, day,
                    priority, time, end, setAppt, alarm);
            items.add(item);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    //Close the cursor.
    cursor.close();

    //Return the items.
    return items;
}
```

The Object Date is my own object, not the Java object. It only contains the methods for what I need.

I have checked and rechecked the query in the debugger. It follows SQLite rules. But it is not pulling anything out of the database, even right after I create a new item for that day. It gets to the `return items;` line and returns an empty ArrayList. I moved through the surrounding days to see if the item was just stored with the wrong day, but it's not. I also checked what day, month, and year are being inserted into the database. They are correct.

I came here to stackoverflow and could not find an answer.

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Please help.

And since this is my first question, any comments on how to improve my question are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the deal. I feel so stupid now. The problem is solved. The reason that it wouldn't work is that in certain places, I had reversed the year and the day on MY OWN Date object constructor. I found that out after putting the year, month, and day directly into the query (and not the question marks). Anyway, I hope that this was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log the exception in your savePlanItem() function, just to be sure inserts are done.

And just a question, where do you open the database in these functions ?

Comment: I open it in the onCreate() method of the application class. Also, I check for an error in the savePlanItem() method by checking the returned id against -1 (Android documentation says that -1 is returned for the id when an error occurs). That said, I will add the log anyway, just to see if anything is different

Comment: I would up vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for trying to help. If you want to see why I had the problem, look on the question page; it's pretty embarrassing. Thanks for your help!